# What are the most likely reasons an application would fail on only one of my servers?

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment, webserver

I have several servers to test new code on.  I primarily push out asp.NET web applications.  Last week, I had an issue where I installed a newly developed web application on three servers.  The three servers all run in separate environments.  The application worked fine on two of them, but consistently crashed on the third server with each web request.  The problem was eventually traced to an in-house developed .dll file being out of date on the third server.

I'm certain that this kind of thing happens all the time.  However, there are numerous things that could go wrong to cause this kind of behavior.

I spent quite a bit of time tracing this problem.  I would like to make a list of things to be suspicious of next time this happens?

What are the most likely reasons that a web application would crash on one of my servers while identical code runs fine on another server?

Comment: Are you asking for common server configuration problems?

Comment: I have a feeling that this question is _way_ too broad. The easiest way to troubleshoot a problem is to note the symptoms and attack the problem from the approach that's presented based on those symptoms. You could do something like you suggest with a flowchart, but I believe that the number of answers you will get and their great disparity will prove less beneficial than you think and more confusing than helpful.

Comment: This question is broad, but it's not entirely general.  I started out with the assumption: "These servers are nearly identical and all the other applications I'm testing run fine on both, so what could possibly be wrong?"  I assumed the two servers were the same and it was a face-palm moment when I found out that one of them had a library out of date.

I'm asking, when two servers are set up to be basically the same, what are the first things I should suspect when something goes wrong with only one of them?

Answer (score 0):

You can start off with a Beyond Compare directory comparison between working and non-working servers.  That can tell you what, if anything, is different in deployed files.  That would have found this particular problem very quickly.

http://www.scootersoftware.com/

Comment: In the particular case I described, I don't think this would help because the .dll that was out of date was in the global assembly cache, not in in the web deployment folder.

However, this would probably help with some other common problems.

Answer (score 0):

**ELMAH** is a good way to keep a pulse on the errors on production applications

http://code.google.com/p/elmah/

Especially if you run it at the server level so that all the errors are posted

Answer (score 0):

You could use Web Deploy to compare the site configuration, content, and if you define the right manifest it could even check for things in the Registry, GAC, COM objects, etc.

It will work for sites running in IIS 6 and IIS 7+ and it can even compare hybrid setups (ie IIS 6 vs IIS 7).

http://blogs.iis.net/msdeploy/archive/2008/02/02/using-ms-deploy-to-compare-sites-or-see-what-components-your-site-uses.aspx

Furthermore it can help you syncronize them as well in case anything is out of date with a single click (command line).